# installing the canonical version of openstack

Tags: networking, maas, canonical, openstack-autopilot

I have been working through setting up my servers for openstack http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack and I am trying to configure the second NIC.

I receive this error in my MAAS

```
Failed to import images from boot source http://maas.ubuntu.com/images/ephemeral-v2/releases/: HTTPConnectionPool(host='maas.ubuntu.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /images/ephemeral-v2/releases/streams/v1/index.sjson (Caused by : [Errno 113] No route to host)
```

This is what I have for eth1 (eth0 is auto with dhcp)

```
# The secondary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.0.0.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
broadcast 10.0.0.255
```

Inside my cluster configuration for eth1 I have the following and it is set to manage dhcp and dns.

```
IP 10.0.0.2
subnet 255.255.255.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255
router ip 10.0.0.1
dhcp low 10.0.0.3
dhcp high 10.0.0.100
static low 10.0.0.101
static high 10.0.0.200
```

The other part to this is no tools are provided to 'properly' configure the second network interface. The documentation says that the Ethernet configuration works, though it doesn't following it word for word. 
What am I missing? Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Does anyone have good general interfaces configurations to make this work?

Update **
The only other thing I can see doing is adding a router for the MAAS Cluster to 'own' and only have one interface in the cluster configuration instead of dealing with both.

*** UPDATE 3/10/2015 ***

The installation has progressed now that the controller owns the router, and it is all being handled on one NIC. Power management exists, can power on / off other servers, however the autopilot doesn't see or recognize nodes that are being controlled or enlisted. 
** The autopilot installer at the terminal never sees the MAAS nodes that are in 'ready' or 'commissioned' state.
Any guidance is appreciated in accomplishing this task.

Comment: Have you confirmed that eth0 actually can get out to the internet?  "No route to host" suggests networking isn't actually set up or isn't functioning or isn't able to reach out to the net.

Comment: it doesn't get out. If I change the settings to DHCP it works fine.

Comment: Hi John, I'm trying to get a picture of what your installation looks like. I don't know what you mean when you say "controller owns the router". Here are two pictures of the basic network layouts we support, could you describe yours based on these? Flat: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7798176/maas-flat-network.png  Split: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7798176/maas-split-network.png

Comment: I posted a more complete networking guide here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/595558/how-should-i-setup-maas-so-that-it-can-be-used-by-the-canonical-openstack-autopi/

Answer (score 0):

When you're on the Autopilot landing page, is the MAAS server registered with Landscape and the connection working (are the first two checks green)?

Comment: This is not answered. As i mentioned before for the update of 3/10 auto pilot doesnt recognize anything when im controlling nodes from the MAAS web page

Comment: @John75077: could you explain that a bit more?  Is the machine listing empty?  Is the "openstack beta" landing page with the checkmarks all red?  screenshots would be helpful.

Comment: @dpb i dont get that far. When running the install it says im not meeting its requirements when in fact i can controll nodes.

Comment: @John75077, ok -- could you post some screenshots of the openstack-install command output?  You can also jump into freenode in #ubuntu-solutions and ping stocachu or mmcc and they can be of help.

Comment: @John75077, Feel free to file a bug at https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues just make sure to provide us with the required files noted in https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md