# How many nodes to use Maas/Juju for Openstack (Juno)?

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I want to do a Proof of concept (Multi node) on MAAS/juju and I'd like to know how many nodes juju needs to install Openstack ?
How many NIC ?
How many network 1,2,3 ? it is possible with 1 network ?

Can I control where the controller, the compute or cinder will be install on my maas cluster ? (which server?)

I don't want to use devstack or other tools "all-in-one"
sorry to ask but on all my researchs, it's still not clear !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the latest Landscape Autopilot, LDS 15.01, then you need at least:

- one machine for MAAS
- one machine for LDS
- 3 machines for OpenStack

Details about the networking setup can be found here:

https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/04/10/maas-network-layouts-for-the-landscape-autopilot/

Or at this askubuntu q&a:

[How should I setup MAAS so that it can be used by the Canonical OpenStack Autopilot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/595558/how-should-i-setup-maas-so-that-it-can-be-used-by-the-canonical-openstack-autopi/)

Comment: Thanks for your help !!
But Have you any idea how Openstack will be install on the maas-cluster ?
where the controller, compute or cinder will be install on my maas cluster ? 

Can I choose to install on 1 specific node my controller for example ?

Comment: Not with the Autopilot. The idea is that it makes those decisions for you.