# Openstack installation on ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: openstack

I am new to Ubuntu and i want to install Openstack kilo versions on Ubuntu 14.04 . I have already checked Openstack installation on ubuntu but i saw Canonical version to install openstack. I am very confused. So please guide me to install openstack kilo on ubuntu. Please refer some documents for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable the Ubuntu Cloud Archive for OpenStack Kilo on Ubuntu 14.04 installations by running the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository cloud-archive:kilo
sudo apt-get update
```

For more info check the following source:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive

For a step by step installation:

http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/install-guide/install/apt/content/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you . One more question what is  Canonical version to install openstack on ubuntu.

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack

Comment: Canonical version, because the PPA is the recent and also the first of its kind. It might be inconsistent - time will say. Also consult http://askubuntu.com/questions/595558 while following along the Canonical version.

Comment: also consult other questions tagged `openstack` that match your need.

Answer (score 0):

Canonical has provided a good web page titled [Ubuntu Openstack Installer](http://ubuntu-cloud-installer.readthedocs.org/en/stable/index.html)

If you follow any of the 3 install methods (landscape, multi-node, single machine) it installs Openstack Kilo for you (at least it did for me) and I am on Ubuntu 14.04 also.

The Single mode requires a fairly beefy pc (i7, lots of RAM, SSD if possible) but it installs all of the Openstack components into an LXC container.

Inside that container other Openstack "services" are started in other "nested" LXC containers.

When you are done you can stop/start the entire Openstack just by stopping/starting the "master" LXC container.

[Installation using the Single mode](http://ubuntu-cloud-installer.readthedocs.org/en/stable/single-installer.guide.html) can take anywhere from about an hour to maybe 2 1/2 hours depending on CPU, Memory, HD-type/speeds.

**NOTE**: *at the lower right of the Single Mode screen there is actually a selector button you can click that toggles to "doc" between guides for Single mode deployment using scripts/code of one of three choices:*

- Stable
- Testing
- Latest

I only mention the above because its hard to notice that selector.

The [Landscape mode](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack) & the [Multi mode](http://ubuntu-cloud-installer.readthedocs.org/en/stable/multi-installer.guide.html) would be used if you were building a more realistic DC lab or deployment.