# openstack-install hangs registering against landscape

Tags: proxy, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I'm behind a proxy, and ran `sudo openstack-install --http-proxy myproxy:port --https-proxy myproxy:port`, and then selected the landscape autopilot. The script made it through bootstrapping Juju, praparing Landscape and Deploying landscape, but now it's going on 4000 seconds registering against landscape, and still says it's downloading the latest landscape autopilot bundle. Is it normal for this script to take this long, or could there be more proxy configuration I need to do to download the latest landscape autopilot bundle? I'm trying to follow instructions from here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the landscape autopilot (Release: 15.01) does not fully support an http_proxy setting.  You will need to have direct internet access from all machines you are testing with.

This answer has a good listing of the sites that you will need access to:

[How should I setup MAAS so that it can be used by the Canonical OpenStack Autopilot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/595558/how-should-i-setup-maas-so-that-it-can-be-used-by-the-canonical-openstack-autopi)