# What is the purpose of the second NIC for the Landscape Autopilot?

Tags: networking, server, maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot

In the process where the configuration happens in the Landscape Autopilot, it says "There must be at least one machine, available in the MAAS cluster, that has both multiple disk and two or more network interfaces connected to the networks that are defined in MAAS."

If I am understanding this right I will have two NIC's on one machine in the network of the MAAS. One NIC will be active for the PXE / WOL and the other is just there doing what?? This question could be asked in Openstack, however this is being followed 'By the Book' from the Canonical web page of how to install the OpenStack Autopilot.

Am I supposed to run the cable from the secondary NIC back into the same network? What purpose does it truly serve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used by Neutron to serve as the bridge for traffic coming in and out of your VMs on the cloud.

Comment: Just to be clear it needs one connection back to the private lan and one out to the internet?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/595558/1102 for the two possible layouts. You can have it connect to "the Internet" but that depends on your requirements.