# openstack: no ping to Instance from neutron-gateway/0 - error "Destination Host Unreachable"

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, ping

I performed a cluster node installation using this guide [OpenStack Charms Deployment Guide].(https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/latest/install-maas.html), where the type of network is a Flat network and the components used are:

- Maas
- Juju
- Openstack.

My lab has the following network plan:

```
                         +-------------+
                              Firewall
                            10.20.81.254
                          +-------------+
                                 | 
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
                              Switch 
      vlan81              vlan81                  vlan81
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
        |                   |                   || || || ||
+--------------+     +------------+        +------------------+
|Maas+Juju           |Juju Gui|            |Openstack
|10.20.81.1          |10.20.81.2           |10.20.81.21-24
+--------------+     +-------------+       +------------------+
                                                     |
                                +--------------------------------------------+
                                Private Subnet-1           Public Subnet-2
                                 10.0.0.0/24                10.20.81.0/24
                                 +---+----+--+              +----+------+
                                 |    |        +----+            |
                                 |    |        |    |            |
                                 |    +--------+ VR +-------------+
                                 |             |    |
                                 +--+-+        +----+
                                 |    |
                                 | VM |
                                 | .9 |
                                 |    |
```

my lab:

```
1 IBM System 3540 M4 Maas (500GB HDD - 8GB RAM - 1 Nic)
1 IBM System 3540 M4 Juju (500GB HDD - 8GB RAM -1 Nic)
4 IBM System 3540 M4 Openstack (500GBx2 HDD - 16GB RAM - 2 Nic)
1 Palo Alto Network Firewall
```

IP plan:

```
Public Network: 10.20.81.0/24
Private Network: 10.0.0.0/24

Maas: 10.20.81.1
Juju: 10.20.81.2
Openstack: 10.20.81.21-24
Gateway 10.20.81.254
Private Network 10.0.0.0/24
Instance: 10.0.0.9 - 10.20.81.215 (floating)
```

[image]

Openstack Router:
[image]

Openstack Security Group:
[image]

Maas route:

```
$: ip route
default via 10.20.81.254 dev enp2s0 proto static 
10.20.81.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.81.1
```

Juju Controller:

```
ubuntu@juju-controller:~$ ip route
default via 10.20.81.254 dev enp8s0 proto static 
10.20.81.0/24 dev enp8s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.81.2
```

Compute Nodes:

```
ubuntu@os-compute01:~$ ip route
default via 10.20.81.254 dev br-eno2 proto static 
10.20.81.0/24 dev br-eno2 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.81.21 
10.38.53.0/24 dev lxdbr0 proto kernel scope link src 10.38.53.1

ubuntu@os-compute02:~$ ip route
default via 10.20.81.254 dev br-eno2 proto static 
10.20.81.0/24 dev br-eno2 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.81.22 
10.104.230.0/24 dev lxdbr0 proto kernel scope link src 10.104.230.1 

ubuntu@os-compute03:~$ ip route
default via 10.20.81.254 dev br-eno2 proto static 
10.20.81.0/24 dev br-eno2 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.81.23 
10.126.34.0/24 dev lxdbr0 proto kernel scope link src 10.126.34.1 

ubuntu@os-compute04:~$ ip route
default via 10.20.81.254 dev br-eno2 proto static 
10.20.81.0/24 dev br-eno2 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.81.24 
10.72.47.0/24 dev lxdbr0 proto kernel scope link src 10.72.47.1
```

Router:

```
$:openstack router show u1804Ro
Password: 
   +-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field                   | Value                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| admin_state_up          | UP                                                                                                                                                                                       |
| availability_zone_hints |                                                                                                                                                                                          |
| availability_zones      | nova                                                                                                                                                                                     |
| created_at              | 2019-02-28T22:27:36Z                                                                                                                                                                     |
| description             |                                                                                                                                                                                          |
| distributed             | False                                                                                                                                                                                    |
| external_gateway_info   | {"network_id": "e2ba9320-b1cb-4fd8-acd8-b4d9df9df819", "enable_snat": true, "external_fixed_ips": [{"subnet_id": "b3ae37b6-487b-4063-8d69-ec849fd9c9c7", "ip_address": "10.20.81.212"}]} |
| flavor_id               | None                                                                                                                                                                                     |
| ha                      | False                                                                                                                                                                                    |
| id                      | fc288112-3fce-405d-9c3f-5451253de4f0                                                                                                                                                     |
| interfaces_info         | [{"subnet_id": "c7fcfa82-ec70-4917-8f24-7074bf22743b", "ip_address": "10.0.0.1", "port_id": "84693247-3f86-4c84-b0f6-aa8bd95c6c16"}]                                                     |
| name                    | u1804Ro                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| project_id              | 1f4809b5083549c1a35c4c023487752c                                                                                                                                                         |
| revision_number         | 8                                                                                                                                                                                        |
| routes                  |                                                                                                                                                                                          |
| status                  | ACTIVE                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| tags                    |                                                                                                                                                                                          |
| updated_at              | 2019-03-01T14:02:46Z                                                                                                                                                                     |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Security Group list

```
$:openstack security group list
Password: 
+--------------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------+
| ID                                   | Name     | Description                 | Project                          |
+--------------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------+
| 57f3fbd9-7574-4116-826f-083a1241bc0f | default  | Default security group      | 3e59e7cde179423abcdce8fe431fbea0 |
| c242b952-8b07-4d25-b24e-ada213cc116f | u1804Sec | Security Group for u1804Pro | 3e59e7cde179423abcdce8fe431fbea0 |
+--------------------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Security Group rule list

```
$:openstack security group rule list
Password: 
+--------------------------------------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| ID                                   | IP Protocol | IP Range  | Port Range | Remote Security Group                | Security Group                       |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 07b3bd3f-cc62-409c-bc65-62eea6c7b3ea | None        | None      |            | 57f3fbd9-7574-4116-826f-083a1241bc0f | 57f3fbd9-7574-4116-826f-083a1241bc0f |
| 34216d9f-f5fc-44a3-9e1a-ac52b0cdc334 | None        | None      |            | None                                 | 57f3fbd9-7574-4116-826f-083a1241bc0f |
| 472eff92-c0f8-4a7e-806d-de98fe066d8f | tcp         | 0.0.0.0/0 | 22:22      | None                                 | c242b952-8b07-4d25-b24e-ada213cc116f |
| 8f101215-759d-48bc-b665-bd72463ecb3d | None        | None      |            | None                                 | c242b952-8b07-4d25-b24e-ada213cc116f |
| a6a0e040-3cc8-4cc3-bedf-2aa1adc52018 | None        | None      |            | None                                 | 57f3fbd9-7574-4116-826f-083a1241bc0f |
| d4346b18-65b3-49a6-9763-05229e468dac | None        | None      |            | 57f3fbd9-7574-4116-826f-083a1241bc0f | 57f3fbd9-7574-4116-826f-083a1241bc0f |
| dc9f8a32-7315-493a-b8ed-9b5919afc2c8 | None        | None      |            | None                                 | c242b952-8b07-4d25-b24e-ada213cc116f |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

anyone can help me to solve that? thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Don't post images. 2. "My issue is shown in the first picture"? <sarcasm>Looks fine to me</sarcasm>. What is your question? 3. Whar does `ip route` show on each system?

Comment: @waltinator You may want to be specific when you say "Don't post images", else people randomly stumbling onto the question may misunderstand. Images  are OK, just not OK of terminal commands and command-line output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update 23/03/19:**

I can ping the virtual eths from neutron-gateway:

From MAAS

```
$: juju ssh neutron-gateway/0
```

then

```
ubuntu@os-compute01:~$ ip netns list
qrouter-fc288112-3fce-405d-9c3f-5451253de4f0 (id: 4)
qdhcp-feb5596f-b201-4e01-9c04-64abd1273d2f (id: 3)
```

ping result on the eth on router:

```
ubuntu@os-compute01:~$ ip netns exec qrouter-fc288112-3fce-405d-9c3f-5451253de4f0 ping 10.20.81.212
PING 10.20.81.212 (10.20.81.212) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.20.81.212: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.085 ms
64 bytes from 10.20.81.212: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms

ubuntu@os-compute01:~$ sudo ip netns exec qdhcp-feb5596f-b201-4e01-9c04-64abd1273d2f ping 10.0.0.2
    PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.32 ms
    64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.096 ms
```

if I try to ping the instance or its floating IP assigned, they're unreachable

```
ubuntu@os-compute01:~$ sudo ip netns exec qdhcp-feb5596f-b201-4e01-9c04-64abd1273d2f ping 10.0.0.9
PING 10.0.0.9 (10.0.0.9) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.2 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable

ubuntu@os-compute01:~$ sudo ip netns exec qrouter-fc288112-3fce-405d-9c3f-5451253de4f0 ping 10.20.81.215
PING 10.20.81.215 (10.20.81.215) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.20.81.215 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.20.81.215 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

its route is:

```
ubuntu@os-compute03:~$ sudo ip netns exec qrouter-fc288112-3fce-405d-9c3f-5451253de4f0 ip route
default via 10.20.81.254 dev qg-2af6bb57-15 
10.0.0.0/24 dev qr-b089085a-11 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1 
10.20.81.0/24 dev qg-2af6bb57-15 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.81.212
```

**Update 01/04/19:**

Changing the type of image uploaded on Opentstack, from LXD (bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64-lxd.tar.) to IMG (bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img), the ping now is working fine.

```
ubuntu@os-compute01:~$ sudo ip netns exec qrouter-fc288112-3fce-405d-9c3f-5451253de4f0 ping 10.0.0.9
PING 10.0.0.9 (10.0.0.9) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.9: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.075 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.9: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.070 ms
```

and its own floating IP

```
ubuntu@os-compute02:~$ sudo ip netns exec qrouter-e933429f-6816-47b3-9e50-581d78243935 ping 10.20.81.220
PING 10.20.81.220 (10.20.81.220) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.20.81.220: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.608 ms
64 bytes from 10.20.81.220: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.550 ms
```

the rest of sets on Openstack are the same used to the begin.